# Check if html is available

Tags: r

I would like to know how can I check if a html is available. If it is not, I would like to control the return to avoid stop the script by error.
Ex:

```
arq <- readLines("www.pageerror.com.br")
print(arq)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is `try()` - it is simpler to work with than `trycatch()` but isn't as featureful. You might also need to suppress warnings as R will report that it can't resolve the address.

You want something like this in your script:

```
URL <- "http://www.pageerror.com.br"
arq <- try(suppressWarnings(readLines(con <- url(URL))), silent = TRUE)
close(con) ## close the connection
if(inherits(arq, "try-error")) {
    writeLines(strwrap(paste("Page", URL, "is not available")))
} else {
    print(arq)
}
```

The `silent = TRUE` bit suppresses the reporting of errors (if you leave this at the default `FALSE`, then R will report the error but not abort the script). We wrap the potentially error-raising function call in `try(...., silent = TRUE)`, with `suppressWarnings()` being used to suppress the warnings. Then we test the class of the returned object `arq` and if it inherits from class `"try-error"` we know the page could not be retrieved and issue a message indicating so. Otherwise we can print `arq`.

Answer (score 0):

`?tryCatch`   'Nuff said. <-- Except, apparently not, because the pageweaver demands more characters in an answer. So, "If a chicken and a half lays an egg and a half in a day and a half, how many eggs do nine chickens lay in nine days?" 
OK, long enough.

Comment: -1 definitely not "nuff said" because `?trycatch` returns no information and using `tryCatch` is not easy to do - an example would be helpful.

Comment: @Abe -- that's what the text at the bottom of the `?tryCatch` output is for.

Comment: the bottom of `?tryCatch` still leaves me (and apparently many others) searching for answers on SO.